# Support for more than one GitHub account in Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'd like to link to a GitHub project that's not on my account, it's on a separate organization account. After linking a GitHub account, it seems that you can't remove that account, nor can you directly link to a project outside the GitHub configuration section.